# LINQ where or filter c#

Tags: c#, linq

I have a collection being returned by a web service. A property of this collection is "StatusCode" which is a string value that can be anywhere from 0 to 5 (don't ask me why it was set up as a string... I didn't schema this). Initially I was going to use LINQ to filter this, then realized that was stupid (why return 100% of the records when I need 20%) and I parameterized my Stored Proc to do this for me.

In any case, I wrote a LINQ query that worked, but for curiosity sake, I imagine there's a better way to do it:

```
var wo = from w in workOrders
    where w.StatusCode == "0"
       || w.StatusCode == "1"
       || w.StatusCode == "2"
    select w;
```

Any suggestions? Correct answer goes to most thorough answer - including either documentation, best practice, etc...

Comment: You can probably use a Contains

Comment: I don't see anything bad in a triple condition like that. It's readable and efficient, who needs more ?

Comment: Is this a LINQ or LINQ to SQL query?

Comment: strictly LINQ on an ObservableCollection. Like I said, I realized how poorly that was thought out, so this is more for my knowledge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var wo = from q in workOrders where int.Parse(w.StatusCode) < 3 select w;
```

Is a cleaner way to do the LINQ query, at least.

Comment: +1 for enum, brain fart, didn't think of that. I also like this methodology the best, its very clean.

Answer (score 2):

```
var wo = from w in workOrders 
         where new[]{"0", "1", "2"}.Contains(w.StatusCode)
         select w;
```

BTW, if you were using an ORM, you could do it in LINQ (like the above) and only pull the 20% from the database ;)

Comment: We'd be using EF if I had my druthers, which I know would only return what I want.

Answer (score 2):

I recently wrote a [blog post](http://www.thecodepage.com/post.aspx?id=28197601-0cae-48a2-aadf-992e073f8690) about a method using extension methods and params.

By adding this extension method to your code:

```
public static bool IsIn<T>(this T source, params T[] values)
{
    return values.Contains(source);
}
```

you can perform your search like this:

```
var wo = from w in workOrders
    where w.StatusCode.IsIn("0", "1", "2")
    select w;
```

It works on any type (as long as you create a good equals method).  Any value type for sure.

Answer (score 1):

You could define an `IsIn()` generic Extension Method:

```
public static bool IsIn<T>(this T value, params T[] values)
{
    return values.Contains(value);
}
```

Then you could write your query like this:

```
var wo = from q in workOrders where w.IsIn("1","2","3") select w;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your method is ok. I don't believe parsing or lookup collection is neccessary for 3 string values (however it certainly isn't wrong). With parsing I'd be afraid of empty strings or nulls (even tho we know that there *should* only be strings 0-5).

If you are anticipating filtering like this on more places you should probably create method (or extension) on WorkOrder that would determine current state more expressively like

```
public static bool IsNotCompleted(this WorkOrder workOrder) 
{
    return workOrder.Status == "0" || workOrder.Status == "1" || workOrder.Status == "2";
}
```

and then

```
var wo = from o in workOrders where o.IsNotCompleted() select o;
```

or (I personally prefer this sytaxe)

```
var wo = workOrders.Where(o => o.IsNotCompleted());
```

Using extension to describe state like this will increase readability and it will be much easier to add/remove status codes in future.