# Operator '||' cannot be applied to operands of type 'lambda expression' and 'lambda expression'

Tags: c#, linq

How do i construct a LINQ `WHERE` clause that contains `OR`?

---

i have a list of objects, and i want to return those that match a search criteria.

The contained objects have many properties, and as long as *any* match the criteria, i want to return it:

```
IEnumerable<Item> list;
String keyword; 
...

var results = list.Where(
      (item => item.Name.Contains(keyword, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
      ||
      (item => item.Description.Contains(keyword, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
      ||
      (item => item.Description.Contains(keyword, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
      ||
      (item => item.ItemType.Contains(keyword, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
      ||
      (item => item.ItemID.ToString().StartsWith(keyword, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
      ||
      (items => items.Value.ToString().StartsWith(keyword, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
);
```

But that fails to compile:

> Operator '||' cannot be applied to operands of type 'lambda expression' and 'lambda expression'

How do i construct a LINQ `WHERE` clause that contains `OR`?

### See also

- [LINQ where or filter c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5954965/linq-where-or-filter-c-sharp)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just do all your tests in the same lambda expression...

```
IEnumerable<Item> list;
String keyword; 
...

var results = list.Where(
      item => item.Name.Contains(keyword, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
      || item.Description.Contains(keyword, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
      || item.Description.Contains(keyword, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
      || item.ItemType.Contains(keyword, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
      || item.ItemID.ToString().StartsWith(keyword, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
      || items.Value.ToString().StartsWith(keyword, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
);
```

Comment: I'm curious as to why this answer got 6 upvotes, and the other three essentially identical ones received none, especially since this was the latest answer added.

Comment: You're right, I had my conception of the meaning of "x minutes ago" backwards.

Comment: @EsotericScreenName i would also say it got my upvote, and accept, because he took the time to copy-paste-fix the entire example from the source (and formatted nicely). The extra work get's extra love.

Comment: @IanBoyd: It consists of various typos: `items` instead of `item`, duplication of `item.Description.Contains...` clause.

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to express each condition inside of a separate lambda expression which is incorrect.

You want to have all of your expressions inside of a single lambda expression:

```
var results = list.Where(item =>
    (item.Name.Contains(keyword, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
    || (item.Description.Contains(keyword, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
    || (item.Description.Contains(keyword, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
    // and so on
);
```

Answer (score 3):

Just a different approach which I think is interesting; it allows a more composable solution if you want it.  You can use a version of [Predicate Builder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) modified for linq-to-objects. Like this:

```
var predicate = DelegatePredicateBuilder.False<Item>();

predicate.Or (x => x.Name.Contains(keyword))
         .Or (x => x.Description.Contains(keyword))
         .Or (x => x.ItemID.ToString().StartsWith(keyword))
         .Or (...); // etc

var results = list.Where(predicate);
```

I've trimmed some of the boilerplate code to just show the gist of the idea.

The [linq-to-objects predicate builder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7094980/461968) is from an answer by Jon Skeet. Code posted here for completeness:

```
public static class DelegatePredicateBuilder
{
  public static Func<T, bool> True<T>()  { return f => true;  }
  public static Func<T, bool> False<T>() { return f => false; }

  public static Func<T, bool> Or<T>(this Func<T, bool> expr1,
                                 Func<T, bool> expr2)
  {
    return t => expr1(t) || expr2(t);
  }

  public static Func<T, bool> And<T>(this Func<T, bool> expr1,
                                          Func<T, bool> expr2)
  {
   return t => expr1(t) && expr2(t);
  }
}
```

Comment: This looks extraordinarily useful; although i have no idea what i'm looking at. C# really is starting to combine the blazing speed of Java with the elegant readability of perl.

Comment: @IanBoyd I first saw the source for predicate builder years ago.  To this day, I still need to see it used to understand it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't combine multiple lambdas, you want to build a boolean expression based on an the or (`||`) combination of your conditions within the `where` clause:

```
var results = list.Where( item => item.Name.Contains(keyword, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
                          || item.Description.Contains(keyword, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the lambda declaration on every comparison... something like:

> var results = list.Where( 
>         (item => item.Name.Contains(keyword, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) 
>         || 
>         item.Description.Contains(keyword, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
>         || 
>         item.Description.Contains(keyword, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) 
>         || 
>         item.ItemType.Contains(keyword, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
>         ||
>         item.ItemID.ToString().StartsWith(keyword, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
>         || 
>         items.Value.ToString().StartsWith(keyword, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) );