# Search Functionality in two model fields for one text box

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to use a single textbox for a search in two model fields: In a textbox I write some letters or a word and click on Search button, so must search in CommonName and in SciName fields (both in the same model) . Here is an example of the controller:

```
 public ActionResult Index(string SearchParam)
 {

     var search = from m in db.Table1
                  select m;

      if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchParam))
      {
         search= search.Where(s => s.CommonName.Contains(SearchParam) ||      
                  s.SciName.Contains(SearchParam));
      }

return View(search)
}
```

CommonName and SciName are from the same model.

The view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
    {    
        <table>
            <th>
            Serch for Name: @Html.TextBox("SearchParam")
            <input type="submit" value="Search" /></th>
        </table> 

    }
```

but Visual Studio display a message saying that "||" operator can't be used with lambda expressions. Somebody knows how to do this search??? Thanks!!!

----- UPDATED----- NO MORE LAMBDA EXPRESSION ERROR -----------

I  checked the code again, and now the error is not displayed... .. but the search is made only with the first part of:

```
search= search.Where(s => s.CommonName.Contains(SearchParam) ||      
                      s.SciName.Contains(SearchParam));
```

it is only made with `s => s.CommonName.Contains(SearchParam)` and the second condition after `||` is just ignored

Comment: what is `m`, `CommonName`, `SciName` ?

Comment: CommonName and SciName are strings .. and m is an object of the model..

Comment: really looks like a bug, try to use `s => (s.CommonName.Contains(SearchParam) || s.SciName.Contains(SearchParam))` if it provides the same error - paste whole error message including error code

Comment: There is no error... it just makes the search with the first condition s.CommonName.Contains(SearchParam)... and ignores the second ... after ||

Comment: I executed the app. and.. searched things I know are in the SciName and doesn't display any data... and with data in the CommonName it works

Comment: try to use `search = search.Where(s => { return s.CommonName.Contains(SearchParam) || s.SciName.Contains(SearchParam); }); foreach (var element in search) System.Console.WriteLine(element);` and place breakpoint at the start of foreach, to debug what is actually happens

Comment: An error in compilation... A lambda expression with a statement body cannot be converted to an expression tree

Comment: ok, we have error, but without code, can you return to original code and provide full error message, it should look like: `Program.cs(38,30,38,32): error CS####: ....`

Comment: At the original code there is not error.. .. its just ignoring the '|| s.SciName.Contains(SearchParam)'

Comment: do you mean that studio do not display message about "operator can't be used with lambda expressions"?

Comment: It doesn't... .. I have it like this `s => (s.CommonName.Contains(SearchParam) || s.SciName.Contains(SearchParam))` but it just ignore the second condition

Comment: sorry, but I'm out ideas why do you write one thing in question and claims another thing in comments, visual studio either provide you with error or it doesnt ignore your code, debug your code to check what actually happens, check the data, use simple for to filter results and compare with LINQ statement, maybe it is real bug and shold be posted to microsoft

Comment: @ASP_beginner: you can check this post to understand what is wrong with your lambda expressions : [Operator '||' cannot be applied to operands of type 'lambda expression' and 'lambda expression'](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8900160/690329).

Answer (score 0):

I just found the problem. It was a authentication issue in other part of the code. Here I leave the complete code:

```
public ActionResult Index(string SearchParam)
        {

            var search1= (dynamic)null;

            var search= from m in db.Table1
                          select m;


            int selec = 0;

            if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {

                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchParam))
                {
                    search= search.Where(s => s.CommonName.Contains(SearchParam) || s.SciName.Contains(SearchParam));
                    selec = 1;
                }

                search1= (from d in db.Table1
                            select d).OrderBy(p => p.CommonName);


            }
            else
            {
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchParam))
                {
                    search= search.Where(s => s.CommonName.Contains(SearchParam)||s.SciName.Contains(SearchParam)).Where(s => s.State.Equals(true));
                    selec = 1;
                }

                search1= (from d in db.Table1
                            where d.State== true
                            select d).OrderBy(p => p.CommonName);
            }

            if (selec == 0)
            {
                return View(search1);
            }
            return View(search);

        }
```